# Find whether car assigned is moving toward customer or moving away customer

Tags: java, logic, analytics, euclidean-distance

Data which available for computation is

1. Driver (lat,lon) x  mins
2. customer (lat,lon) x - millisecond
3. Driver (lat,lon) x-1 mins
4. Driver (lat,lon) x-2 mins

I have set of location in which i want to find the whether car is moving towards or moving away from a customer .

Data which i have is customer location and car's last 3 polled location (which use to push each minutes).

There is two method in which i can find .

1. Distance calculation.
2. Angle in which car moved.

Which would be the best way to go .  Do both method required to be combined if so, how some glance ?

Comment: What do you mean by "assigned"? Is the assignment to a driver somhow relevant for the task? What is stopping you from simply calculating the distance from the person for the three positions and checking if it in- or decreases?

Comment: Ditto, also consider that distance in a city is probably not the euclidian one, since the car will have to follow streets...

Answer (score 0):

Moving towards a customer = getting closer = distance is less than it was.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    double personX = 1, personY = 1;
    double carX1 = 4, carY1 = 4;
    double carX2 = 2, carY2 = 3;

    if (distance(personX, personY, carX1, carY1) > distance(personX, personY, carX2, carY2)) {
        System.out.println("Getting closer");
    }
}

static double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    double dx = x1 - x2;
    double dy = y1 - y2;
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

Comment: Distance Method will not give correct result as that data which i had is actual location polling happen in Road

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.